# PyQT - How to get coordinates of an image selection

Tags: python, image, pyqt, selection, coordinates

I have to get the coordinates of a section of an image in PyQT.
At first I need a widget that can show an image (png or jpeg) but I don't know which can do this. And then I must select a portion of this image with a rectangle and get the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the rectangle.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can display images:

1. with a `QLabel` and its method `QLabel.setPixmap`, OR
2. with a `QGraphicsScene`/`QGraphicsView`, OR
3. in a `QWidget` by redefining the `paintEvent` method and using e.g. `QPainter.drawPixmap`.

Once the image is displayed you can use a `QRubberBand` [(example)](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QRubberBand.html) to allow and display the selection.